# Git - pulling causes deleting files

Tags: git

After running the 'git pull origin' against the main branch, all new files, which already are committed, in my branch are marked as deleted. I have to run

```
git reset
```

and

```
git checkout ---.
```

to recover those files.

In this situation, how to merge the main branch into my branch?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need after editing the local files is commit the files with the following command:

```
git pull origin
```

And make the change of files

```
git add .
git commit -m "text"
```

Then you should commited pulling the files to the remote repository with following command:

```
git push origin
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The error is caused by reverting code changes on my branch. I have to create another branch to keep my code changes.